# Calling Method in Operator Method Weird Behavior

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

IntBuf.h

```cpp
#ifndef CDEVTOOLS_INTBUF_H
#define CDEVTOOLS_INTBUF_H

#include <string>
#include "ArrayTools.h"

class IntBuf {
private:
    int* values_;
    int capacity_;
    int length_ = 0;

public:
    IntBuf(int capacity);

    void Add(int val);

    std::string ToString();
};

void operator+=(IntBuf buf, int val);

#endif //CDEVTOOLS_INTBUF_H
```

IntBuf.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#include "IntBuf.h"

IntBuf::IntBuf(int capacity) {
    this->values_ = new int[capacity];
    this->capacity_ = capacity;
}

void IntBuf::Add(int val) {
    printf("adding %d, current length: %d\n", val, length_);
    
    assert(length_ < capacity_);
    values_[length_++] = val;
    
    printf("added %d, new length: %d\n", val, length_);
    std::flush(std::cout);
}

std::string IntBuf::ToString() {
    return ArrayToString<int>(values_, length_);
}

void operator+=(IntBuf buf, int val) {
    buf.Add(val);
}
```

I don't understand why the 2 following implementations output different things

**Implementation 1 - Using IntBuf::Add**

```cpp
#include "IntBuf.h"

int main() {
    IntBuf buf = *new IntBuf(10);
    buf.Add(34);
    buf.Add(23);
    printf("%s\n", buf.ToString().c_str());
}
```

output

```
adding 34, current length: 0
added 34, new length: 1
adding 23, current length: 1
added 23, new length: 2
[34, 23]
```

**Implementation 2 - Using operator+=(IntBuf buf, int val)**

```cpp
#include "IntBuf.h"

int main() {
    IntBuf buf = *new IntBuf(10);
    buf += 34;
    buf += 23;
    printf("%s\n", buf.ToString().c_str());
}
```

output

```
adding 34, current length: 0
added 34, new length: 1
adding 23, current length: 0
added 23, new length: 1
[]
```

ArrayTools implementation:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<typename Type>
std::string ArrayToString(Type* values, int length) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "[";
    int imax = length-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
        ss << values[i] << ", ";
    }
    if(imax >= 0) ss << values[imax];
    ss << "]";
    return ss.str();
}
```

I'm confused as to how using the operator overloaded function could be different then calling IntBuf::Add, since the overloaded operator should also use IntBuf::Add

Comment: `*new` is a guaranteed memory leak in any code.  `IntBuf buf = *new IntBuf(10);` should just be `IntBuf buf(10);`

Comment: As the duplicates mention, `void operator+=(IntBuf buf, int val)` creates a **copy** of your `IntBuf`.  You modify it, but the copy is destroyed at the end of your function.

Comment: @DrewDormann how is `*new` a *guaranteed* memory leak? Couldn't I add `delete &buf;` at the end to de-allocate the memory for the object?

Comment: No.  Bad things would likely happen, because `buf` is a local variable on the stack.  It's a copy of the object that you allocated with `new`, whose address you have lost.